# How to get HTML table content from an in-complete webpage (HTML only) online?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, html-table, jsoup

**Question:** How to get table content in HTML by Java?
**Requirement:** Has to be online page, not local file.

I want to extract the url of the 1st subject at:

```
https://discussions.apple.com/community/ipad/using_ipad?view=discussions#/?page=3
```

I tried following code to get 1st subject at page 3

```
String url_page3 = "https://discussions.apple.com/community/ipad/using_ipad?view=discussions#/?page=3";
String key = "td.jive-table-cell-subject > a[href]";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url_page3).maxBodySize(0).timeout(0).get();
Element e = doc.select(key).first();
System.out.println(e.attr("abs:href");
```

It returns the first subject on page 1 (even I changed connected url to page 4, page 5, ...)

But why does this happen? Is there any other method I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple. The hash tag does not matter for the server so it sends only the first page. I guess the other pages are send out by AJAX so you need to check the network traffic to find that url. Than you can also read the next pages.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution by using Jsoup or other library to access the complete page, which allowed me to get the final html file?

Comment: For the first page it is okay in that way you have implemented. Try pressing F12 in the most browsers it opens the development tools, there you should be able to track the AJAX requests. That urls you are interested in right now. Since I'm using a mobile right now I cannot do that for you now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it now. But I'm so new on network progrmming. I'm looking forward to your further direction.

Comment: Still have no idea how to do it

Comment: I found the url: https://discussions.apple.com/community/ipad/view-threads.jspa?start=60&range=30&numResults=30&tags=&containerType=14&containerID=2040&filter=all you can change the parameters by yourself?